# Cpu/Server Overload on server

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have my own server where I hosted my sites. 
I got this email ...

> IMPORTANT: Do not ignore this email. This is cPanel cpuwatch on
>   server.xxxx.com! While processing, the cpu has been maxed out for more
>   than a 6 hour period.  The current load/uptime line on the server at
>   the time of this email is  19:49:33 up 85 days,  1:46,  0 users,  load
>   average: 12.16, 11.94, 11.92

In cpanel I looked Daily Process Log, and I received the following list, 
Top Processes:

```
vukcrven        61.0    [php] <defunct>
root        47.5    /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/bin/spamd -d --allowed-ips127.0.0.1 --pidfile/var/run/spamd.pid --max-children3 --max-spare1
srpska      33.0    /usr/bin/php /home/srpska/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-o-matic/cron.php
radniksi    28.0    /usr/bin/php /home/radniksi/public_html/wp-admin/edit-comments.php
pubambik    25.5    /usr/bin/php /home/pubambik/public_html/index.php
mysql       20.0    /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir/usr --datadir/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --usermysql --log-error/var/lib/mysql/server.voiptel.ba.err --open-files-limit48364 --pid-file/var/lib/mysql/server.voiptel.ba.pid
srpska      19.5    /usr/bin/php /home/srpska/public_html/index.php
mysql       19.1    /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir/usr --datadir/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --usermysql --log-error/var/lib/mysql/server.voiptel.ba.err --open-files-limit48364 --pid-file/var/lib/mysql/server.voiptel.ba.pid
mysql       18.7    /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir/usr --datadir/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --usermysql --log-error/var/lib/mysql/server.voiptel.ba.err --open-files-limit48364 --pid-file/var/lib/mysql/server.voiptel.ba.pid
vukcrven    18.5    /usr/bin/php /home/vukcrven/public_html/index.php
```

What is problem? And How can I solve problem?

You should check the server to see why the load is so high and take
 steps to lower the load.  If you want stats to continue to run even with a high load; Edit
 /var/cpanel/cpanel.config and change extracpus to a number larger then 0 (run
 /usr/local/cpanel/startup afterwards to pickup the changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like spam assasin (spamd) is using up a large amount of resources (which it has a tendancy of doing)

Another item is a cron job running for Wordpress, if you are not using wordpress I suggest you remove the plugin.

If you have shell access you can restart SpamAssasin using: /scripts/restartsrv_spamd

If not, contact your provider's support and they can do it for you.

What are the specs of the cPanel account?

Comment: Its my server, i have root and i reboot server now its ok, i have only ... vukcrven        30.0    [php] <defunct>